# DataIntegrityViolationException in service SPRING BOOT

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, server

I am trying to save an instance of offer to my Data base. However, it gives the following exception:

`DataIntegrityViolationException. Could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [UK_gx37scrkaxomyvyre37ohexbh]`

when I try to save the instance in my repository. Here the code:

```
 @Transactional
    public Long addOffer(Long buyerId, ReqBody.Offer data){
        try{
            Optional<Offer> offer = offerRepository.findOffer(data.productId, buyerId);
            if(offer.isPresent()){
                if(offer.get().getStatus().equals(Offer.CANCELED) || offer.get().getStatus().equals(Offer.REJECTED)){
                    offer.get().update(data.productPrice,data.insurance,data.delivery,data.paymentMethod);
                    offerRepository.save(offer.get());
                    notifyNewOffer(offer.get());
                    return offer.get().getId();
                }else {
                    throw new ControllerException("This user has already made an offer on this product");
                }
            }else{
                User buyer = userService.getUser(buyerId);
                Product product = productService.getProductById(data.productId);

                Offer newOffer = new Offer(buyer, product, data.productPrice, data.insurance,
                    data.delivery, data.paymentMethod);
                product.addOffer(newOffer);
                buyer.addOffer(newOffer);

                offerRepository.save(newOffer); //exception here
                notifyNewOffer(newOffer);
                return newOffer.getId();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please share your unique key named `UK_gx37scrkaxomyvyre37ohexbh`. Also the error says that the data you're trying to store already present in DB (according to Unique Key). It may be a case of dirty reads i.e. transaction management. But for further assistance, I need Unique key constraint. Also check transaction management. You can use Requires.NEW in transactional annotation.

Comment: yeah I figured it out latter that it was due to unique in productId of offer